# How to modify query string to plain url using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following html form :

```
<div class="row form">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SITE_URL.'location'); ?>">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10 no-p-m">                      
            <select class="form-control" id="basic" name="location" required>
            <?php
            $get_location = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM product_sub_area");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($get_location) == 0 ) {
                $choose = 'No City found';
            } else {
                $choose = 'Choose City';
            }
            ?>
            <option value=""><?php echo $choose; ?></option>
            <?php                                         
            while($get_location_result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_location) ) {
                $location_id = (int) $get_location_result['psub_area_id'];
                $location_name = htmlspecialchars($get_location_result['psub_name']);
                echo "<option value='$location_id'>$location_name</option>";
            }
            ?>                    
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 no-p-m" id="basic">  
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default filter-search" value="BROWSE">
        </div> 
    </form>                
    </div>
</div>
```

When I submit this form the url is showing like bellow :

> http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/location?location=1

But I need to show this type of url :

http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/location/carlifonia

here `/location/` is a page called `location.php`. I am hiding page extension using `.htaccess`.

So from `location.php` page I want to get `$_GET['location']` value = `$location_id`

for eg.

$_GET['location'] = 1 or 2 ( select tag option value)

**Existing .htaccess code**

```
ErrorDocument 404 not-found.php
RewriteEngine On        

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^location/([\w-]+)$ location.php?location=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's just how HTML forms using the GET method work; they put the values into the URL like that. Why not use javascript to forward the user to the correct URL instead of the form?

Comment: You can use jQuery to do this. Capture the form submit, create the link, and then send the user to the correct link. In your PHP script, you need to get the 'location' value from the url and not from the $_GET then. I would suggest using a php framework as they help you with capturing Urls and also a lot of other features. Consider Laravel :)

Comment: which method is more easy ? using js/jQuery OR .htaccess ? How can I do this ?

Comment: @JaspalSingh *you need to get the 'location' value from the url and not from the $_GET* - That's not true. The URL is being rewritten. PHP receives `location.php?location=$1`.

Comment: @shibbirahmed You would probably use *both* JS *and* mod_rewrite to accomplish this.

Comment: @Mike, what I am saying is that he needs to capture the form submit and not use the GET method. Then he can redirect the user to the url that he will create via javascript (http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/location/carlifonia) and will have full control of it.

Comment: @JaspalSingh Yes, that part I am agreeing with. That's what I suggested as well in my first comment.

Comment: Can you guys give me an example ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed Are you using any JS frameworks, such as jquery?

Comment: Yes I am using jQuery

Comment: I personal prefer to do this using .htaccess because in my other pages I am using query string to get id value. If i use .htaccess then I can show all my querying to plain url. Like what I am asking to you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how this can be accomplished in jQuery:

First, add an `id` to your `<form>` tag so you can access it easily:

```
<form id="formname" class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SITE_URL.'location'); ?>">
```

You also have a duplicate `id` called `"basic"`. Make sure you leave it only on the `<select>` tag and remove the other one.

Then in your JS:

```
$("#formname").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc = $("#basic option:selected").text();
    window.location.href = '/freelancer/happiechef/location/' + loc;
});
```

This will forward the user to the URL, for example `http://localhost/freelancer/happiechef/location/carlifonia`. Then .htaccess will rewrite this URL to `location.php?location=california`.

Comment: Great idea but what happened if someone edit this js code by inspect ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed What's wrong with them looking at the JS code?

Comment: I mean can someone change this `window.location.href` location ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed They can put whatever they want in there. But your script should be able to handle invalid locations.

Comment: @shibbirahmed Users don't have to modify the JS, they can just modify the URL after they are redirected.

Comment: If pass a query string like : siteurl/location?location=3. Here is 3 is a id number which actual value is = "carlifonia" then can I make : siteurl/location/carlifonia ?

Comment: This will pass the location *name* to PHP, not the location ID. In PHP you would then have to use the name when selecting the location from the database. I also recommend adding a `UNIQUE` flag to that column to make sure you can't get duplicate values if more than one place might have the same name, e.g. London, England or London, Ontario.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike, It's real helped me a lot :)